# why is theta in a restricted interval? (Polar coordinates)

Tags: polar-coordinates

What is the polar equation of the circle of radius 1 whose centre lies at the cartesian point (1,0)?

So I got the correct answer of r=2cos(θ)
But then is says theta is in the interval (-π/2)≤θ≤(π/2)

Why is this?

Thank you.

Comment: That should be $r^2 = 2\cos\theta$ I think. In which case, in order for the function to be $1$-$1$, we need $\cos\theta>0$

Comment: @Mathmo123 no this is the correct answer, you can get an intuition about this by seeing at $\theta = -\pi/2$ we have $r=0$ and $\theta = -\pi/4$ we have $r = \sqrt{2}$, $\theta = 0, r=2, \theta = \pi / 4, r = \sqrt{2}, \theta = \pi / 2, r = 0$ which if you convert all these to cartesian you get $(0,0),(1,-1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,0)$. Of course this isn't a proof but just for intuition ;D

Comment: Ah missed a factor of $r$ in my calculations!

Comment: Either way the answer is still that we need $\cos\theta$ to be positive as we want $r\ge0$

Answer (score 1):

The circle is $(x-1)^2+(y-0)^2=1$ so $x^2-2x+1+y^2=1$. Now use $x=r\cos(t),~y=r\sin(t)$ to find that circle in the polar form: $$r^2\sin^2(t)+r^2\cos^2(t)-2r\cos(t)+1=1$$ Or $$r^2-2r\cos(t)=0$$ This means that if $r\neq 0$ then $r=2\cos(t)$. For making sure of what's noted about $t$, just draw that circle. You certainly see that for what values of $t$, the whole plot is being done. It should be restricted.:

[image]

Comment: why does it need to be restricted?  Babak S